# Excel Online (many users but only one user is allowed to edit)

Tags: excel, excel-services, excel-web-access-webpart

i have given many users have access to a excel sheet in Onedrive (excel online).
Thats ok. 
Is it possible to give only one user access to sheet to edit. (the other users have to wait!)
I want that the other users can't get access to sheet when an other user is editing the sheet. 
Also one by one. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in sharepoint. only option is when you check out then other users can still use the older version in read only mode.